# How to limit get_posts()?

Tags: get-posts, limit

I've been researching this for the last 3 days. I'm triyng to limit the maximum amount of posts retrieved by `get_posts()`.

I have this chunk of code:

```
// all filters should be applied here
$args = array(
    'nopaging'                  => true,
    'post_type'                 => get_option('ip_slug'),
    'posts_per_page'            => $ip_ipp,
    'limit'                     => 100,
    'orderby'                   => $ip_order,
    'order'                     => $ip_order_asc_desc,
    'author'                    => $author,
    'suppress_filters'          => false,

    'meta_key' => $ip_meta,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $ip_key,
        )
    ),
    'cache_results' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
//
```

The `limit` parameter does not work.

**UPDATE #1:** I want to use, say, `5` posts per page and use multiple queries on the same page using `get_posts()` (not `query_posts`, not `WP_Query`) and I want to limit the database query to `100`. I can't use the `paged` parameter, due to multiple dynamically created loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem, I have used the `posts_per_page` parameter with a value of `100` and used [jPages](http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/) for jQuery pagination.

**Explanation:** As I needed to pull a limited number of posts - in my case, `210` - I wanted to use both pagination and a query limit. As this seems to be impossible using `get_posts()`, I used the `posts_per_page` parameter with a value of `210` and implemented a jPages pagination. Not the most elegant solution, but it does the job.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `posts_per_page` or `numberposts`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters

EDIT: Regarding your edit. You cannot have the `posts_per_page` different to the `LIMIT` in the SQL query. `get_posts()` [creates an instance of `WP_Query` and returns it](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1839) using the [`posts_per_page` as the LIMIT](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3058).

Comment: `posts_per_page` does not limit the actual `get_posts()` query. Also, `numberposts` does not work.

Comment: Then why do you say in your comment that you used `posts_per_page`? If you are paginating you set the `paged` parameter to the page number and `posts_per_page` will limit the amount of records. There is no `limit` parameter in WP_Query

Comment: My solution is not a true WordPress one. I display 100 posts and use a jQuery pagination technique. So the question is not yet answered. I need a `posts_per_page` solution combined with a `limit` parameter. I only need `get_posts()` to retrieve 100 posts, so I can paginate them, I don't know, 5 or 10 per page. There is no way to limit the `get_posts()` query, without using the `posts_per_page` parameter.

Comment: Also, I cannot use the `paged` parameter, as I am using multiple queries on the same page.

Comment: You could use `offset` with `posts_per_page` to get around not being able to use `paged`, or as you have multiple queries on the page you would probably be better off creating a new WP_Query object for the secondary queries.

Comment: The queries are created dinamically, so there's no primary or secondary one. I don't want to use `offset`, I want to use `get_posts()` with `posts_per_page` set to `99999` and limit the database query to `100`.

Comment: There is no way to have `posts_per_page` = 99999 and the database query to 100 because `posts_per_page` is what sets the limit in the query. I cannot see a reason to do this, maybe update your question with more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my question. I need a `limit` parameter to pass to the SQL `LIMIT` query.

Comment: The posts_per_page is what actually sets the LIMIT in the SQL. So, you're not making any actual sense, posts_per_page and the SQL LIMIT are the exact same thing. You cannot separate them.

Comment: Thank you @Otto. I usually use `posts_per_page` to define the number of posts per page to display. So I have 10 pages, with 5 posts per page, that's a total of 50 posts. I cannot set `posts_per_page` to 50 in this case, correct? I need to set it to 5.

Comment: Yes, you would set it to 5, because you want to get 5 posts, not 50. The name of the variable is self-explanatory: *posts per page*.

Answer (score 2):

The "limit" parameter does not work because there is no such parameter in get_posts or any other query in WordPress.

You can use `posts_per_page` to set the number of posts to retrieve, and `offset` to have it skip certain numbers of posts. These are the only parameters you can use, and together, they change the resulting LIMIT in the SQL query that is performed.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a `get_posts()` query for `100` posts and `5` posts per page?

Comment: You're confusing two different things here. The number "100" doesn't enter into it at all. You have 100 posts. You want to show five of them. You set posts_per_page to 5. End of statement. How many total posts or pages you have doesn't make any difference at all.

Comment: What if I have 10000 posts? How do I limit the query? Isn't there a parameter or a hook or a filter to modify the query?

Comment: There are many ways to modify the query, but my point is that you're not pulling out 10000 posts, you're only pulling them out 5 at a time. So the only value you care about is "5". How many posts there are is irrelevant, you're not getting all the posts in a single query.

Comment: Thanks Otto, I solved the problem using a different approach. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have the next parameter enabled which blocks pagination, thus any limitation losts sense:

`'nopaging'                  => true`

Switch it to "disabled" or delete it. By the way, get_posts() function limits posts to 5 by default in latest WP-version. Or you can use posts_per_page attribute to directly set the limit or do it with admin panel (Settings-> Reading).

Comment: This what fixed it for me.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the `pre_get_post`-hook to get the number of posts that you want to display:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'your_function_name' );
```

Comment: And _how_ would the OP use that hook?